# FATAL EXCEPTION in LiveData 'dispatchingValue' method: No virtual method iteratorWithAdditions()

Tags: android, setvalue, android-livedata

I have a view with a viewModel that observes my LiveData. I get my data from a Repository (which gets data either from Room or WebAPI). 
I have implemented a NetworkBoundResource abstract class so I can manage 
data loading in a cleaner way. MediatorLiveData object is used in this class:

```
private final MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
```

The crash happens at the first line of my constructor:

```
@MainThread
public NetworkBoundResource() {

    result.setValue(Resource.<ResultType>loading(null));

    final LiveData<ResultType> dbSource = loadFromDb();

    result.addSource(dbSource, new Observer<ResultType>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ResultType newData) {
            result.removeSource(dbSource);
            if(shouldFetch(newData))
            {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
            } else {
                result.setValue(Resource.success(newData));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method iteratorWithAdditions()Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$ListIterator; in class Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap' appears in /data/app/com.example.smostofi.upswing-XxPvhI837wneIYVTOrU2Dw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes25.dex)
                                                                            at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:145)
                                                                            at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:293)
                                                                            at android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
                                                                            at com.example.smostofi.upswing.data.Util.NetworkBoundResource.<init>(NetworkBoundResource.java:44)
```

First time asking a question here, hopefully I provided enough info!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: found any solution? facing the same issue.

Comment: No :| personally I could not find any solution yet.

Comment: i found it yayy.. Posted an answer if it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have added the **same dependency more than once** in your Gradle.

I had a same **issue**. The reason was, I had added the Appcompact library twice in the Gradle as below :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile rootProject.ext.supportLibAppCompat
```

By removing one, the issue got resolved.

Please check your Gradle for the same. Hope it helps :)

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! I could not figure out where the duplication existed, but I guess that was my issue too, cause I replaced my whole dependency list with one from a similar app , and now it is working! thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It is not duplicate dependency issue, just change your life cycle version from

```
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha4'
```

to

```
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9'
```